# Android: Getting ListView item position onscreen after layout

Tags: android, listview

I am currently working on a fragment with functionality similar to Roman Nurik's sticky scrollview technique here:

http://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks

However, I want to use it with a ListView and have it stick both at the top and the bottom of the screen.  I've have been somewhat successful by using two hidden views at the top and the bottom of the screen, and having the list unhide them when the correct item reaches the top or bottom using the following:

```
//Similar to Roman's Stick ScrollView
 @Override
public void onScrollChanged() {


    if(scrollListen){
        if(mMovingClock != null && mMovingClock.getTop() <= list.getTop()){
            //Log.i("DraftSync", "View at " + String.valueOf(mMovingClock.getTop()));
            clockTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            clockTop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


        if(mMovingClock != null && mMovingClock.getBottom() >= list.getBottom()){
            clockBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            clockBottom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem I have is that if my targeted list item (mMovingClock) is one of the initial items shown onscreen at fragment start, the list.GetTop() method returns zero.  I have searched extensively, and understand that this is because it's measuring it before it is rendered in position onscreen, but I am enabling scrollListen where I feel it should be:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_draft, container, false);
     list = (ObservableListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.draft_queue);
     list.setCallbacks(this);

 ...


  list.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
             new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onGlobalLayout() {
                     onScrollChanged();
                    scrollListen = true;

                 }
      });


    return rootView;

}
```

I think I am following the example correctly, but scrollListen is being set to true before the mMovingClock is properly measured.  Can anyone figure out why this view always returns 0 for getTop() and getY() until it scrolls off screen once?  After that all is well.

Any advice?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I feel silly for missing this, but here it is:

In the xml for my layout I had my ListView set as wrap_content instead of fill_parent.  I spent so much time looking at the fragment coding that I never considered checking the layout.

Thanks to Flavio, as it seems his answer should work, but in the end was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule the call to getTop() for the next layout pass. At this time, your view will have been measured. Try this out:

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
list.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                onScrollChanged();
                scrollListen = true;
            }
        });    
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method did not work.  The call seemed delayed, but did still happen too soon.  Also,  I did have to add a run() method to the new Runnable to get this to work.

Comment: I added a Log event for each time onGloballayout runs, and each time it returned 0 for the view position I am trying to find.  I even tried moving the boolean toggle to switch the first time the screen is touched, but the view still returns 0.  Any idea why a View 3 positions down on a list would return 0 for getTop() and getY()?